# Accessing values in project/Dependencies.scala file in scala code in subproject

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a multimodule scala project with the following structure -

-A/
-B/
-project/ (root project)
-build.sbt (this has build definition for all the subprojects)

I have an object declared in the project/ folder (lets call this object Dependencies) which contains various constants . Is it possible to access a variable declared in project/Dependencies.scala in scala code inside a subproject(A or B) without creating a dependency of any of the subprojects  on the root project.
Please let me know if I need to clarify further.

Comment: You can only manage to access it in build of the submodule, not in the `src` code (which can hardly make sense anyway)

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. Is it possible to create a custom setting key in the build.sbt and access that inside the sub project?

Comment: As said nothing in the build is seemlessly available as value or function the code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make some code from your build definition available for the code in the project, you can use [sbt-buildinfo](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo) plugin. It's mostly adapted for setting/task keys, but you can use it for any other values defined in your build too.

The way it works is very simple: it uses `sourceGenerators` to generate a piece of Scala code (with the values from the build) that will be available to the rest of your project sources. So if you don't want to use `sbt-buildinfo`, you can also generate sources directly. See sbt documentation on [Generating files](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto-Generating-Files.html).